# Bulk File Editing

Tags: file-management, text-search

I am looking for a program that searches all the files in a folder and changes the matching words.
It would be better if it contained Regex.

Comment: Welcome aboard. I posted an answer, and I am sure that it is what you are looking for, ***BUT*** I had to do some mind-reading, because you did not tell us  which operating system you use (I gave you a cross-platform Java app). Also, if you are willing to pay, please state a budget, otherwise use the [tag:gratis] tag. The more information that you give us, the better we can help you. Please read [ask]. And, once again, welcome aboard :-)

Comment: on *nix systems there are already sed/awk... Do you want a command line or GUI tool?

Comment: @Mawg I apologize for not giving enough information. The program you're talking about is exactly what I want. There is free, cross-platform and has interface. I will be more explanatory in my next questions. Thanks for everything.

Comment: From your comment below, it sounds like you should also have specified Turkish language (or Unicode) support in the question. See how the more details you give, the better answer you get? :-)   Anyway, welcome, and I am glad that you got what you wanted.  Let's hope that we can help you more, and that you can help others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [FAR - Find And Replace](https://sourceforge.net/projects/findandreplace/)

> Search and replace operations on file content across [sic] multiple files.
>   Recursive operations within entire directory trees. FAR comes with
>   support for regular expressions (regex) over multiple lines, automatic
>   backup and various character encodings. Run grep like extractions to
>   condense or rearrange sources, or perform bulk file renaming.
>
> Features
>    •Recursive search
>    •Regular expressions over multiple lines
>    •Simultaneous replacement operations on multiple files
>    •View matches,
>   preview changes

[image]

Comment: oops, the program does not support Turkish characters.

Comment: I found the [Find And Replace program](http://findandreplace.io/) and it works well.